# OpenAPI - swagger-ui.html unable to infer base URL

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

I'm trying to add swagger-ui (OpenAPI 3.0) to a Spring Boot application.

Added the openapi-ui maven dependency.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
    <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

but loading /swagger-ui.html, we get an alert box with the following message

Unable to infer base url. This is common when using dynamic servlet registration or when the API is behind an API Gateway. The base url is the root of where all the swagger resources are served. For e.g. if the api is available at http://example.org/api/v2/api-docs then the base url is http://example.org/api/. Please enter the location manually:

and openapiconfig is

```
@Configuration
public class OpenApiConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
        return new OpenAPI().info(apiInfo());
    }

    private Info apiInfo() {
        return new Info()
                .title(API_INFO_TITLE)
                .description(API_INFO_DESC)
                .version(API_INFO_VER)
                .license(apiLicence());
    }
}
```

Any Suggestions for workaround?

Answer (score 1):

I was having this same issue and resolved it by adding the following property.

springdoc.swagger-ui.use-root-path=true

you can also resolve programmatically by adding a serverItem in your OpenAPI bean creation;

openApi.addServersItem(new Server().url("https://example.com").description("Example Host"));